# Does django-oauth-toolkit handle pkce with oath2?

Tags: authentication, django, oauth

I am trying to implement oauth2 to my django app. I tried to use django-oauth-toolkit. I think their documentation is outdated and could not find any mention of `pkce`.

Also, I could not find any example or blog post from the internet. If my understanding is correct i have to generate `code_verifier`, and `code_challenger` first. Then I have to append those in request as a parameter. Then django-oauth-toolkit will do the rest. Am I right?

Is there even django+oauth2+pkce successfully integrated

Answer (score 1):

Yes as of v1.3 https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id8

for a blog see:
https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/authorization-code-with-pkce-on-django-using-django-oauth-toolkit

But I must admit, I am still struggling with getting the initial authorization step working, as it seems to force me to login to the Django app.